# Kerberos and NTLM authentication

Tags: windows-7, networking, active-directory, kerberos, ntlm

Q1) How do I force Windows 7 client to always use Kerberos authentication protocol talking to other machines on network irrespective of whether using host name or IP address?

Q2) Similarly, how do I force Windows 7 client to always use NTLM authentication protocol talking to other machines on network irrespective of whether using host name or IP address?

Please let me know if there is any registry settings to achieve the same.

Comment: Please clarify; are you assuming that these options are opposing or mutually exclusive? NTLM and Kreberos are not commonly used by the same protocols so its not an either or scenario.

Comment: I recently experienced issue that I am unable to connect shared folder (using map network drive as it requires credentials of different user account rather than logged on user account) using host name of server where network share resides. 

However, I am able to access network share via IP address successfully.

I checked and found that Name resolution is also working fine. So DNS is not as cause of issue. 

Only thing I can come up with from the top of my head is that name uses Kerberos when authenticating but IP uses NTLM.

Comment: @FrankThomas: That's not true; SMB has had Kerberos support via SPNEGO for many, many years. (I've used it even with Windows XP against both Windows and Samba 3.)

Comment: @Alex: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322979/kerberos-is-not-used-when-you-connect-to-smb-shares-by-using-ip-addres

Comment: So do you mean that accessing network share / shared folder never uses Kerberos authentication irrespective of Host name or IP address of server where share resides?

Comment: I stand corrected. I  have been under the impression that NTLM sat atop any service negotiation.

Comment: Guys, Please let me know what are other possible steps to further diagnose and isolate cause of issue to resolve the problem?

Comment: @grawity Could you please share Microsoft article of Kerberos support in SMB?

Comment: You're assuming your name resolution will use DNS. If you're using just a hostname on a local Windows network, then DNS will most likely not be used to resolve the hostname, but instead NetBIOS. (see [Microsoft TCP/IP Host Name Resolution Order](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/172218/microsoft-tcp-ip-host-name-resolution-order)) "name uses Kerberos when authenticating but IP uses NTLM" this is not correct.

Comment: As it stands this question appears to be an [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info); to avoid that I would suggest you edit and rewrite it to be about your actual problem, not about your supposed solution.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: In my AD domain environment, NetBIOS is disabled.So I am pretty sure NetBIOS is not being used.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: This is my actual problem. As far as my understanding is concerned, it could be authentication issue. I was just sharing my view and understanding. So I would suggest don't assume the things and please provide solutions if you have any.

Comment: I have lots of solutions to fix why you can't connect by host name, but that's not what you're asking here, so good luck (and my educated guess of an answer: You can't force it like you want).

Comment: @TECHIE007: Well if you have lots of solutions, I would still insist please provide. Please don't take my comments personally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68415/discussion-between-alex-and-c007).